# Can we integrate IOS application with OneLogin?

Tags: ios, single-sign-on, saml, openid-connect, onelogin

I need to integrate an IOS application with OneLogin SSO. I am not getting any IOS related API in OneLogin's developers page.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"?

If you're looking to provide SSO your best bet is to either implement SAML or OpenID Connect via a web flow.

Comment: "Integration" means that I want to configure IOS application in Onelogin so that we may leverage SSO functionality of OneLogin for that IOS application.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want SSO functionality, I highly recommend you start by building a web-based login flow using iOS Webview (with sharing)

And as long as this web-based login implements either SAML or OpenID connect, not only will this support SSO between applications on the same IOS device, it will also work with any other Identity Provider that supports SAML or OIDC.

And since you're doing this via a shared web view, once you establish the users' identity in one application, their SSO session will be shareable between all other iOS applications that use the same mechanism.